# CSS perspective shape URL doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to use a trapezoid shape made with CSS to house a link. But it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if it's because it's unsupported or because the code is bad. Seems like it should work! Anyone know why?

To clarify, I know the trapezoid works, but the *link* inside the trapezoid is dead.

My Code:

```css
.box {
  width: 180px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  left: 10%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 34px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 3px #27628e;
  top: -5%;
  bottom: -11%;
  left: -1%;
  right: -5%;
  z-index: ;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-50deg);
  transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-50deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><a href="http://google.com">google.com</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It works in IE 11, Firefox and Chrome for me.

Comment: You mean you can click on google.com and it goes through? I can only highlight the text, not actually click the url.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant that your trapezoid doesn't work. I can't click the link, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.box a{
position:relative;
}
```

And it will work to click on the url.

```css
.box {
  width: 180px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  left: 10%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 34px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 3px #27628e;
  top: -5%;
  bottom: -11%;
  left: -1%;
  right: -5%;
  z-index: ;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-50deg);
  transform: perspective(50em) rotateX(-50deg);
}
.box a{
z-index:999;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><a href="http://google.com">google.com</a>
</div>
```

Comment: In fact, big `z-index` is unnesessary, `position:relative` already moves the `a` element higher in the stacking context than absolutely positioned pseudo element.